# Attempting to log to a SQL Server database, but it doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-2.1, serilog

I'm attempting to log to SQL Server. From what I found it looks like it should be right but it still doesn't seem to be logging. Can you see if there's anything I'm doing in this code? Sorry about posting the code as a picture, it wasn't formatting right for me here.

I tried attempting this in a way that is a little closer to how it'll actually, but still not having any luck.

[image: Path where the info should be going to in the database.]

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .Enrich.FromLogContext()
           .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString: "",
                 tableName: "Logs"
                , schemaName: "LOG"
                , autoCreateSqlTable: true,
                 restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information)
           .CreateLogger();
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}

public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<ValuesController> _logger;

    public ValuesController(ILogger<ValuesController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Start:");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Start:");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Start:");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Start:");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Start:");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Start:");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Start:");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Start:");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Start:");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Start:");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Start:");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Start:");
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
 }
```

Comment: Post the *code* not a screenshot of the code. Screenshots don't compile. YOu should mention you use Serilog too. Your code doesn't contain a valid connection string either. Did you replace `Connection String Here` with a real connection string?

Comment: How do you know that logging doesn't work? The table seems to be created according to the settings

Comment: BTW your code never sets the Serilog logger (`Log.Logger =logger;`) and .NET's logging is configured *after* you execute all logging calls

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't set the default Serilog Logger so all logging calls are lost. You should add

```
Log.Logger=logger;`
```

This is shown in the [Serilog.AspNetCore](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore) repo page:

```
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting web host");
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseSerilog(); // <-- Add this line;
}
```